# Obtaining percentages from a 2d density plot

Tags: python, kernel-density, scipy.stats

I've got a 2d kde plot with contours overlying a hexbin plot. I would like to set the contours and have them show as percentages. An example would be having the contours aligned with the 90% probability or 50% probability. Is there a simple method to do this?

Below is the code and figure obtained, also data is available should it help: [1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flk70g9oCeWCe77QBy4RgIOSyORfUb-I/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116512878716245502822&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

xls = pd.ExcelFile('CSL-results.xlsx')
df = xls.parse("TAL"); TAL = df.dropna()

TALx = TAL.values\[:,0\]
TALy = TAL.values\[:,1\]

xmin = 0
xmax = 80
ymin = 0
ymax = 1

X, Y = np.mgrid\[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j\]
positions = np.vstack(\[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()\])
TALvalues = np.vstack(\[TALx, TALy\])
TALkernel = stats.gaussian_kde(TALvalues)
fTAL = np.reshape(TALkernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6), dpi = 200)
ax = fig.gca()
cfsetTAL = ax.contour(X, Y, fTAL, colors='#6c2d6c')
ax.clabel(cfsetTAL, inline=1, fontsize=6)
Hex_TAL = plt.hexbin(TALx,TALy, gridsize=50, mincnt=1, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out how to do it by manually comparing it to the seaborn kdeplot levels to the contour levels. I'm not a fan of this method as it requires a bit of manual iteration so if anyone has a more automated (and better) method please feel free to comment.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns

xls = pd.ExcelFile('CSL-results.xlsx')
df = xls.parse("TAL"); TAL = df.dropna()

x = TAL.values\[:,0\]
y = TAL.values\[:,1\]

xmin = 0
xmax = 80
ymin = 0
ymax = 1

X, Y = np.mgrid\[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j\]

positions = np.vstack(\[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()\])
values = np.vstack(\[x, y\])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6), dpi = 200)
ax = fig.gca()
fmt = {}

strs = \['50%', '70%', '80%', '90%'\]
sns.kdeplot(data=df,x="Confining Pressure", y="TAL", fill=False, levels=\[0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9\], colors='r')
cfset = ax.contour(X, Y, f, colors='k', levels=\[0.078, 0.108, 0.130, 0.158\])
for l,s in zip( cfset.levels, strs ):
    fmt\[l\] = s

ax.clabel(cfset,cfset.levels\[::1\],inline=True,fmt=fmt, fontsize=6)
Hex_TAL = plt.hexbin(x,y, gridsize=50, mincnt=1, cmap='Blues')

plt.show()
```

[image]